# LibGdx widget position

Tags: java, libgdx

Hello I'm new in LibGdx ! How can I remove this space ! :[Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5FNU.png)

```
    level = new Label( mapHelper.getVillage().getLevel(),skin);
    leveltext = new Label("Level:",skin);
    upgradeButton = new TextButton("incrase Level",skin);



    // adding to my coustom Window
    this.add(leveltext).align(Align.bottomLeft);
    this.add(level);
    this.add(upgradeButton);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your window resizes to its content. And above your 3 actors, there is more content which stretches the width of the window causing the gap.

If you want all 3 actors aligned to the bottom left you could probably, just before adding the actors to the window, call:

```
this.defaults().align(Align.bottomLeft);
```

Another thing you can do is enable debug lines.

To do this, first call:

```
table.setDebug(true);
```

Then in your render method, after drawing the stage, call:

```
Table.drawDebug(stage);
```

This will display lines showing bounds, margins and spacing to help you understand what is going on more easily.

More on tables and debugging [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Table#debugging).